# Route a resource to "/" and still get other resoruces to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I  route my profiles to "/".
I use FriedlyID gem so if you have
a user_name like "ror_user", the route looks like:

```
http://localhost:3000/ror_user
```

root_path still works because it doesn't use index action.

```
resources :profiles, :only => [:show, :edit, :update], :path => "/"
```

This works fine, but I want to use other resources.
Like I want to use

```
resources :cookies
```

and /cookies get this error:

```
Couldn't find Profile with id=cookies
```

Q: How to tell Rails, that only route to profiles#show when there is a matching profile. Or how to overwrite profiles routing when there is an action with same name. Or maybe the whole concept is wrong :).

Comment: Did you try place `resource :cookies` above the :profiles?

Comment: Also you have to restart your server each time you change your config files, such as `database.yml`, `routes.rb` etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that your `profile` route is below your `cookies` route. You should also use reserved slugs to make sure that no one can have an id that might conflict with another route.